# ansible unable to read encrypted credential.json

Tags: shell, ansible-2.x

**Ansible Playbook**:

```
cat sitecode_refresh.yml
---
- name: Run sitecode_refresh.py
  hosts: localhost
  vars_file:
    - credential.json
  tasks:
    - name: Run sitecode refresh script
      no_log: false
      shell: |
        scl enable python27 bash &&
        which pip &&
        pip2 install virtualenv=="16.7.10" &&
        virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 sitecoderefresh &&
        source sitecoderefresh/bin/activate &&
        pip2 install -r requirements.txt &&
        python sitecode_refresh.py --spreadsheet_id="abcxyz" --worksheet_name="Testing" &&
        deactivate
...
```

Running it produces error like below.

```
ansible-playbook -k -K sitecode_refresh.yml --ask-vault-pass
"Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"sitecode_refresh.py\", line 165, in <module>", "    main()", "  File \"sitecode_refresh.py\", line 145, in main", "    client = authenticate_to_gspread()", "  File \"sitecode_refresh.py\", line 96, in authenticate_to_gspread", "    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_PATH, SCOPES)", "  File \"/home/aagashe/dev/scripts/sitebuilder/sitecoderefresh/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py\", line 197, in from_client_secrets_file", "    client_config = json.load(json_file)", "  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py\", line 290, in load", "    **kw)", "  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py\", line 338, in loads", "    return _default_decoder.decode(s)", "  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 366, in decode", "    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())", "  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 384, in raw_decode", "    raise ValueError(\"No JSON object could be decoded\")", "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"
```

Provided encrypted credential.json but still it is giving me error as above.
I encrypted credential.json with the below command.

```
ansible-vault encrypt credential.json
```